# What are the best JQuery plugins for boxes with a close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a regular box on a page. When the user clicks the close button , it disappears.

Comment: Sounds like a nice story

Comment: 21k rep and this is the best you can do for asking a question? Strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI has a pretty well featured dialog box:

> [jQuery UI - Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

There's also blockUI:

> [jQuery BlockUI Plugin (v2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [jQueryUI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a plugin.

```
$('#box a.close').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('#box').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really that hard to implement in JavaScript?

```
<a onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">X</a>
```